# Rails 6 fails to import yarn dependency: Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg, webpacker

I added the rainbow-code javascript dependency to my rails 6 app with

```
yarn add rainbow-code
```

added a file in `app/javascripts/packs/rainbow.js` and tried requiring it

```js
const rainbow = require('rainbow-code')
```

When I reload the page I get

```
browser.js:208 Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
```

If I look in `node_modules/rainbow-code/src/rainbow-code.js` I see

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/env node                                                                                          
  2 /* eslint-disable */                                                                                                     
  3 var fs = require('fs');                                                                                                 
  4 global.Rainbow = require('../dist/rainbow.js');                                
  5                                                                                                     
  6 var files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/language');                                
  7 for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {                                              
  8     require('./language/' + files[i]);                                               
  9 }                                                                                             
 10                                                                        
 11 module.exports = global.Rainbow;                                
 12 delete global.Rainbow;                                                
 13 /* eslint-enable */
```

So it's a shell script starting with a shebang that's trying to be parsed as a javascript file which obviously won't work. What's the best way to load this dependency?

Comment: It seems a [bug](https://github.com/ccampbell/rainbow/issues/213) from Rainbow.

Answer (score 0):

The library’s package entry points to the node implementation, which explains the behavior you’re seeing.

It looks like the browser version lives in a sub directory of the project. Try this instead:

```
import rainbow from ‘rainbow-code/dist/rainbow’
```